# Translate exception messages in Java

Tags: java, exception, translate

I tried a program that can translate exception messages into another language. Most exceptions or fault messages from Java are displayed in English, but I want to change at least for the exception class that they are translated into the Indonesian language, because I'm from Indonesia.
I have been trying to use lexer and parser concepts to do the lexical analysis of some program code to match with a grammar that there is but the result is not perfect. For example in my question before, I made that rule with ANTLR.

Is there another solution to translate a message fault or exception of the English language into another language?

Comment: Do you ask about an automated translation from english to indonesian language? Like google translate, for example?

Comment: yeah like that..
but this is about exception, i mean when the user enter some code and the the code with compile. if the that code is wrong the exception can display that error but not in english. i just wont the message in indonesia. how to costum that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the getLocalizedMessage() method to get an internationalized message. For a usage example, see http://refactormycode.com/codes/339-internationalize-exceptions